# What is Dispatcher Servlet in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-dispatching

In this image (which I got from **[here](http://maestric.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?w=&h=&cache=cache&media=java:spring:spring_mvc.png)**), *HTTP* request sends something to *Dispatcher Servlet.*

[image]

My Question is what does *Dispatcher Servlet* do?

Is it something like getting the information thrown from the web page and throwing it to the controller?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

The job of the *DispatcherServlet* is to take an incoming URI and find the right combination of handlers (generally methods on *Controller* classes) and views (generally JSPs) that combine to form the page or resource that's supposed to be found at that location.

I might have

- a file `/WEB-INF/jsp/pages/Home.jsp`
- and a *method* on a class

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value="/pages/Home.html")
  private ModelMap buildHome() {
      return somestuff;
  }
  ```

The *Dispatcher servlet* is the bit that "knows" to call that method when a browser requests the page, and to combine its results with the matching JSP file to make an html document.

How it accomplishes this varies widely with configuration and Spring version.

There's also no reason the end result has to be web pages.  It can do the same thing to locate *RMI* end points, handle *SOAP* requests, anything that can come into a servlet.

Comment: Great riposte, now a question how come the DispatcherServlet identifies the class name and method name too. Can you show me an example of a configuration where i have two classes and two method names and how DispatcherServlet catches the right request.

Comment: It actually scans the class path on start up for that annotation and makes a mapping of the "/pages/Home.html" to the Class + Method.  If you had two methods that both had "/pages/Home.html" with no other restrictions in their annotation, that would be an error and it will toss exceptions at you.

You can also wire it together with XML if you're oldschool.

Comment: Do we need a `Dispatcher Servlet` xml file when using Annotation Based `@RestController` ?

Comment: @viper in web.xml we always need to configure dispatcher servlet even though you use annotations or xml configurations

Comment: Is there any other type of servlet?

Answer (score 95):

In Spring MVC, all incoming requests go through a single servlet. This servlet - `DispatcherServlet` - is the front controller. Front controller is a typical design pattern in the web applications development. In this case, a single servlet receives all requests and transfers them to all other components of the application.

The task of the `DispatcherServlet` is to send request to the specific Spring MVC controller.

Usually we have a lot of controllers and `DispatcherServlet` refers to one of the following mappers in order to determine the target controller:

- [`BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.html);
- [`ControllerBeanNameHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/ControllerBeanNameHandlerMapping.html);
- [`ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping.html);
- [`DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html);
- [`SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.html).

If no configuration is performed, the `DispatcherServlet` uses `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` and `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` by default.

When the target controller is identified, the `DispatcherServlet` sends request to it. The controller performs some work according to the request 
(or delegate it to the other objects), and returns back to the `DispatcherServlet` with the Model and the name of the View.

The name of the View is only a logical name. This logical name is then used to search for the actual View (to avoid coupling with the controller and specific View). Then `DispatcherServlet` refers to the [`ViewResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html) and maps the logical name of the View to the specific implementation of the View.

Some possible Implementations of the `ViewResolver` are:

- [`BeanNameViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/BeanNameViewResolver.html);
- [`ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html);
- [`FreeMarkerViewResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/FreeMarkerViewResolver.html);
- [`InternalResourceViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html);
- [`JasperReportsViewResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/jasperreports/JasperReportsViewResolver.html);
- [`ResourceBundleViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ResourceBundleViewResolver.html);
- [`TilesViewResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesViewResolver.html);
- [`UrlBasedViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html);
- [`VelocityLayoutViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/velocity/VelocityLayoutViewResolver.html);
- [`VelocityViewResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/velocity/VelocityViewResolver.html);
- [`XmlViewResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/XmlViewResolver.html);
- [`XsltViewResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/xslt/XsltViewResolver.html).

When the `DispatcherServlet` determines the view that will display the results it will be rendered as the response.

Finally, the `DispatcherServlet` returns the `Response` object back to the client.

Answer (score 82):

I know this question is marked as solved already but I want to add a newer image explaining this pattern in detail(source: spring in action 4):

[image]

**Explanation**

When the request leaves the browser **(1)**, it carries information about what the user is asking for. At the least, the request will be carrying the requested URL. But it may also carry additional data, such as the information submitted in a form by the user.

The first stop in the request’s travels is at Spring’s DispatcherServlet. Like most Java- based web frameworks, Spring MVC funnels requests through a single front controller servlet. A front controller is a common web application pattern where a single servlet delegates responsibility for a request to other components of an application to perform actual processing. In the case of Spring MVC, DispatcherServlet is the front controller.

The DispatcherServlet’s job is to send the request on to a Spring MVC controller. A controller is a Spring component that processes the request. But a typical application may have several controllers, and DispatcherServlet needs some help deciding which controller to send the request to.

So the DispatcherServlet consults one or more handler mappings **(2)** to figure out where the request’s next stop will be. The handler mapping pays particular attention to the URL carried by the request when making its decision.
Once an appropriate controller has been chosen, DispatcherServlet sends the request on its merry way to the chosen controller **(3)**.

At the controller, the request drops off its payload (the information submitted by the user) and patiently waits while the controller processes that information. (Actually, a well-designed controller performs little or no processing itself and instead delegates responsibility for the business logic to one or more service objects.)
The logic performed by a controller often results in some information that needs to be carried back to the user and displayed in the browser. This information is referred to as the model. But sending raw information back to the user isn’t sufficient. It needs to be formatted in a user-friendly format, typically HTML. For that, the information needs to be given to a view, typically a JavaServer Page (JSP).
One of the last things a controller does is package up the model data and identify the name of a view that should render the output. It then sends the request, along with the model and view name, back to the DispatcherServlet **(4)**.

So that the controller doesn’t get coupled to a particular view, the view name passed back to DispatcherServlet doesn’t directly identify a specific JSP. It doesn’t even necessarily suggest that the view is a JSP. Instead, it only carries a logical name that will be used to look up the actual view that will produce the result. The DispatcherServlet consults a view resolver **(5)** to map the logical view name to a specific view implementation, which may or may not be a JSP.

Now that DispatcherServlet knows which view will render the result, the request’s job is almost over. Its final stop is at the view implementation **(6)**, typically a JSP, where it delivers the model data. The request’s job is finally done. The view will use the model data to render output that will be carried back to the client by the (not- so-hardworking) response object **(7)**.

Comment: I have a question please, how it select the view in case of returning JSON object  that we see in the browser, does it return to the same URI if there is no logical view selected?

Comment: @Nesrin it's been ages since you asked but here's an answer : You put a special annotation just above the `@Controller` method called `@ResponseBody` indicating that the returned response should be directly written on HTTP response body, not to be placed in a Model or be resolved as view whatsoever.

Answer (score 51):

`DispatcherServlet` is Spring MVC's implementation of the [front controller pattern](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/frontcontroller-135648.html).

See description in the Spring docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet).

Essentially, it's a servlet that takes the incoming request, and delegates processing of that request to one of a number of handlers, the mapping of which is specific in the `DispatcherServlet` configuration.

Comment: Is it something like events in Flex, where i get dispatch events from a one MXML to another or to server. 

Can i have more than one DispatcherServlet in my appication.

Do each class files have a separate DispatcherServlet.

Comment: There's usually only one front controller. This is regardless of the models and views you have. It just brings specific models and views together.

Comment: @theband: You *can* have multiple `DispatcherServlets`, if your architecture makes more sense that way, but usually there's no reason to.

Answer (score 6):

We can say like `DispatcherServlet` taking care of everything in Spring MVC.

At web container start up:

1. `DispatcherServlet` will be loaded and initialized by calling
   `init()` method
2. `init()` of `DispatcherServlet` will try to identify the Spring
       Configuration Document with naming conventions like
       `"servlet_name-servlet.xml"` then all beans can be identified.

Example:

```
public class DispatcherServlet extends HttpServlet {

    ApplicationContext ctx = null;

    public void init(ServletConfig cfg){
        // 1. try to get the spring configuration document with default naming conventions
        String xml = "servlet_name" + "-servlet.xml";

        //if it was found then creates the ApplicationContext object
        ctx = new XmlWebApplicationContext(xml);
    }
    ...
}
```

So, in generally `DispatcherServlet` capture request URI and hand over to `HandlerMapping`. `HandlerMapping` search mapping bean with method of controller, where controller returning logical name(view). Then this logical name is send to `DispatcherServlet` by `HandlerMapping`. Then `DispatcherServlet` tell `ViewResolver` to give full location of view by appending prefix and suffix, then `DispatcherServlet` give view to the client.

Comment: This is a nice explanation. Your point number 2 says that the DispatcherServlet will try to identify the Spring Configuration Document with naming conventions like "servlet_name-servlet.xml". However, I have seen projects which used name like "dispatcher" only, and it works fine. I too have tried that. But I do not know why?

Answer (score 4):

You can say Dispatcher Servlet acts as an entry and exit point for any request. Whenever a request comes it first goes to the Dispatcher Servlet(DS) where the DS then tries to identify its handler method ( the methods you define in the controller to handle the requests ), once the handler mapper (The DS asks the handler mapper) returns the controller the dispatcher servlet knows the controller which can handle this request and can now go to this controller to further complete the processing of the request. Now the controller can respond with an appropriate response and then the DS goes to the view resolver to identify where the view is located and once the view resolver tells the DS it then grabs that view and returns it back to you as the final response. I am adding an image which I took from YouTube from the channel Java Guides.

[image: Dispatcher Servlet in Action]

Answer (score 0):

Dispatcher Controller are displayed in the figure all the incoming request is in intercepted by the dispatcher servlet that works as front controller.
The dispatcher servlet gets an entry to handler mapping from the XML file and forwords the request to the Controller.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    </bean> 

          <bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee" />
        <property name="username" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean> 

</beans>
```