# Spring controllers vs HttpServlet performance-wise

Tags: spring, performance, servlets, controller

I'm working on a java web app with a simple web layer based on [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) (classes that inherit [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) class).
My app is a real-time app, meaning functionality is measured (among the rest) by response time.

I would like to use [spring controllers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html) (DispatcherServlet) instead of my current servlets.
Should I expect the same performance?

Comment: You should user spring controllers, it will have nearly same performance, along with lots of spring framework features.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer **No**

Spring Controllers are the "C" part of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and are based on Servlets; and spring's [dispatcher servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769467/what-is-dispatcher-servlet-in-spring) loads all information and forwards the request to matching/corresponding controller for request processing.

While [servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213541/what-is-java-servlet) are the base of the java web application; there is minimal overhead there.