# Spring MVC: WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this class in my Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8.

I have this web.xml file.

```
...
<servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>ecolabelWeb</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>

                <url-pattern>/newdesign/manage/manageapplications</url-pattern>    
                <url-pattern>/newdesign/manage/manageapplications/</url-pattern>
                <url-pattern>/newdesign/manage/manageapplications/*</url-pattern>

                <url-pattern>/newdesign/manage/home</url-pattern>    
                <url-pattern>/newdesign/manage/home/</url-pattern>
                <url-pattern>/newdesign/manage/home/*</url-pattern>

                <!-- Explicitly mention /welcome.do for usage as welcome page -->
                <url-pattern>/welcome/welcome.do</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
...
```

and this controller:

```
/** 
     * 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/newdesign/manage/home", 
                              "/newdesign/manage/home/",
                              "/newdesign/manage/manageapplications", 
                              "/newdesign/manage/manageapplications/"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String manageApplications    (@ModelAttribute("aplicationListForm") final AplicationListForm aplicationListForm,
                                         HttpServletRequest request,
                                         Model model ) throws ExecutionException {


        User sessionUser = (User)request.getSession().getAttribute(Const.SESSION_USER);
        ..
}
```

this URL works properly

```
/newdesign/manage/manageapplications
```

but with this one `newdesign/manage/home`

I got this error

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/devices/newdesign/manage/home]
```

I am really getting crazy !

I also tried to put it in another method with the same result

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newdesign/manage/home", 
                              "/newdesign/manage/home/"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String cbHome    (Model model ) throws ExecutionException {
    ..
}
```

This URL is working
http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices/newdesign/manage/manageapplications
not this one (?!)
http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices/newdesign/manage/home

Comment: devices is you application context ?

Comment: yes: http://127.0.0.1:7001/devices/newdesign/manage/home

Comment: You shouldn't map your servlet to the urls of the controller. By default the mappings are done inside the mapping of the dispatcher servlet. Next to that `/newdesign/manage/home` already implies `/newdesign/manage/home/`.  You should map your servlet to `/` or `/*` to make it work or configure your request mappings to use the complete url instead of the last part.

Comment: What do you mean ?  remove it from web.xml ?

Comment: @AmadeuCabanilles, Are you sure that the form that request this */newdesign/manage/home* gets embedded with the extension ? Like `<form action="/newdesign/manage/home.do" method="...">`

Comment: It is a GET , I put it on the browser

Comment: I mean that maybe you missed the *.do*. Btw, According to the method this *AplicationListForm* will be bound to form's properties/values , thus if you directly hit it on browser nothing gets bound.

Comment: cant see anywhere any controller mapped to `/devices/*` so i suppose , Spring is doing its job properly by throwing the exception. Also , as mentioned by @M.Deinum , you have placed the URL mappings in both the controller and the web.xml , so if someone f.e. wanted the `/newdesign/manage/home` , he should hit `localhost:8080/newdesign/manage/home/newdesign/manage/home`. Check the posted answer , and read carefully the examples you ve been using

Comment: also regarding your post , *this URL works properly `/newdesign/manage/manageapplications`* , could you post , the whole URL you are requesting , and it works properly....?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration doesn't work because in your web.xml you have limited your application to work only with these url:

```
<url-pattern>/newdesign/manage/manageapplications</url-pattern>    
<url-pattern>/newdesign/manage/manageapplications/</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/newdesign/manage/manageapplications/*</url-pattern>
```

This is a tipical web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

With this configuration you are telling Spring to use the [dispatcher servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769467/what-is-dispatcher-servlet-in-spring) mechanism to handle the incoming requests and the view rendering. This way  he can handle all the url you are defining in controllers, like `/newdesign/manage/home`.

You need to create the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file where you will configure the dispatcher.

See this link for more detailed informations: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/